# infinate scroll loading second page over and over

Tags: jquery, google-app-engine, pagination, infinite-scroll

I am trying to use the jQuery plugin [Infinate Scroll](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll).

The problem I'm running into is that when I scroll, it keeps loading the second page.  So I have

```
results page 1
results page 2
results page 2
results page 2
results page 2
No more results.
```

It does come to an end which is weird, I would think it would just keep going on forever.

Why does page 3 never load.  Is anyone familiar with the inner workings of infinite scroll and know what may be happening.  It seems like the next button is never updated and the same cursor is used each time.  Do I need to make a change to my pagination system?

My next link is in the form www.mysite.com/page?cursor=al8sj6fa1jq3io4cm page 3 would be similar but would be a different cursor.

My Code

```
$('#feed').infinitescroll({
  debug: true,                      
            // enable debug messaging ( to console.log )
  navSelector  : "div.feedNavBar:last",            
                 // selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden)
  nextSelector : "div.feedNavBar:last .nextBTN",    
                 // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
  itemSelector : "#feed div.feedItem"       
                 // selector for all items you'll retrieve
});
```

Comment: It seems unlikely anyone can help unless you show us the relevant code. Clearly this doesn't happen to everyone using the plugin, so the bug must be in your code somewhere, but we can't help you fix it if we can't see it.

Comment: It seems the problem is in how the plugin guesses at future next pages.  It is breaking down the next URL and guessing at what the next page will be.  It doesn't know how to break down app engine cursors so it can't increment past the first good cursor.  Is there a way to use cursors and have urls in the form /page?pageId=2

Comment: No, there's no practical way to do that. You'd need to modify infinite scroll to take a callback function that defines the URL of the next page, I think.

Comment: How bad is it to store the cursor in a session array then use pageId to look up what cursor is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fork here modifies the plugin to do what you're after: https://github.com/thatericsmith/infinite-scroll/blob/343cd297c70f1f8a486cd02cea28cf826b7af7c5/jquery.infinitescroll.js